# Automate windows with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, macros

I have been trying to do this right, but I have not been able to. I have a folder with lots and lots of files and I would like, to go trough all of them, read their names and if there is a string like "_NOT" anywhere in the name I would copy that file to another folder, at the end I would zip that folder then delete the folder and move the zip file to another location. If the zip file at that location already exists I would rewrite it.

Simple right? I would do that with ease from a VBA Macro in Excel but I have no idea how to do that from windows daily.

I just can't seem to find a good tutorial for this.

Would appreciate  any help or directions to a good tutorial that has this covered.

Cheers!

Comment: SO is not a code generator where you simply describe a task and get the code for it. You'll have to show some effort to get help. What have you tried yet? And btw, there is no "simple" way to create zip files in batch without some 3rd party tool. Do you have WinZIP/RAR/7-zip installed? To give you some hints, check out these topics in batch programming: the FOR command, string operations (replacing), the IF EXIST statement, the COPY command, the DELETE command. After dealing with these things try to write your code. If you face some problems doing this, come back and ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
CLS

REM Before you use this, make sure to set the paths. 
REM Make sure you download the 7z command line utility, and plug the path in.


set pathtoFolder=""
set destination=""
set sevenZipdir=""

FOR /R %pathtoFolder% %%G IN (*_NOT) DO (
  echo %%G
  xcopy "%%G" %destination% 
)

%sevenZipdir% a -tzip _not.zip %destination%
RMDIR /Q /S %pathtoFolder%
```

Comment: Hello! you have answeared my question pretty acuratly, i had to go trough code 1 by 1 to get what it all means but after a bit of tinkering i found all the syntax errors and got the code to run with one problem, the command xcopy returns "invalid number of arguments" or if i set just COPY it says "system cannot find the specified file" i tried the commands manually in cmd and tried to echo the variables but i see no problems annywhere

Comment: i think so but i am not shure, should it be entire path or just filename ? right now its %%g is C:\correctpath\nameofthefileimsearchin.txt and %destination% is "C:\correctpathtofolder" tho in echo the %%g has no (") sign on either side but destination does

Comment: Try %pathtoFolder%\%%G.

Comment: Tried, still the same, i am affraid that its the problem with windows 10, but I did try to run it as Administrator and I am Administrator of the PC myself

Comment: Place quotes around %%G. Let me update my post. Copy my post exactly.

Comment: That worked !     just a few things 2nd last line "sevenZip" is wrong variable name, RMDRIR  needs to be RMDIR and folder needed to be removed is  destination, for my needs atleast. Thanks aggain its not the entire thing I need, but im sure I will figure the rest out no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98128/discussion-between-uros-grum-and-iluvlinux).